# how to fix Cumulative layout shift in next js

Tags: performance, next.js

```
<div className="m-auto antialiased">
      <Meta />
      <Header testimonial={!!testimonials?.length} statistics={statistics} />
      <div>
        <OrganizationsSection />
        <AboutUsSection />
        <ServicesSection />
        <TestimonialSection />
        <AcademicPartnersSection />
        <BookMeetingSection />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

this is the outer most component and in light room the element causing the shift is detected as the outer div     `<div className="m-auto antialiased">` as it is the outermost wrapper addind height dosent solve the issue. How do I fix CLS issue

[image]